# Datamapper - weird may not be NULL error

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I'm using DataMapper in a simple application to track sales. I have a `Day` class, like this:

```
class Day
include DataMapper::Resource

property :id,            Serial, :key => true
property :date,          DateTime
property :bestseller,    String
property :total_money,   Decimal
property :total_sold,    Integer
property :total_orders,  Integer

has n, :sales

end
```

and a `Sales` class:

```
class Sale
include DataMapper::Resource

belongs_to :day

property :id,     Serial, :key => true
property :name,   String
property :amount, Integer
property :value,  Integer
end
```

When trying to add a new `Sale` to the database, like so:

```
s = Sale.new(:day => Day.get(1), :name => "Foo", :amount => "42", :value => "42"
```

I get this error when calling `save`.

```
DataObjects::IntegrityError at /sell
sales.date may not be NULL
```

I have no `date` property in `Sale`, so I'm not sure where this is coming from. First I thought that the `Day` object I'm getting doesn't have a day set, so I did `d = Day.get(1).date = Time.now` and `save`d it, but this doesn't resolve the error.

What did I break?

**EDIT** The sqlite3 schema

```
CREATE TABLE "sales" (
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  "name" VARCHAR(50), 
  "amount" INTEGER,
  "value" INTEGER, 
  "day_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "drink_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX "index_sales_day" ON "sales" ("day_id");
CREATE INDEX "index_sales_drink" ON "sales" ("drink_id");
```

Comment: The syntax of the error looks like it may be coming from the database. Could you go into a db console and check the schema (post it here)?

Comment: How would I do that? I forgot to mention, the database is SQLite3.

Comment: Just type `sqlite3 <name_of_database_file>` at the console, and `.schema sales` once in. `.help` for help and `.quit` to quit. If this is production data, avoid doing anything else (although you could take a copy of the file to work with)

Comment: @NeilSlater I added the schema. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I was wrong about the schema being related to this, there is no `sales.date` column. However, it's useful information, so worth leaving in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed it. Apparently, I had an old `date` property at one point in `Sale`. I entered the ruby interpreter, required my model and used `DataMapper.auto_migrate!` to reset the entire database. This fixed the problem.